# How to deal with apps that use a REST API but need a realtime chat (Socket.io)

Tags: node.js, rest, api, socket.io, backend

I am planning to develop a mobile app which will retrieve data from a node.js REST API but also needs an integrated realtime chat with groups up to 12 people. How should I develop the backend in this case? Build everything with Websockets, including simple data communication or using both a REST API and Websockets?

I already developed an app with a REST API which later got a realtime chat with socket.io but using both feels wrong to me (especially when you use a PHP REST API and node.js for socket.io :D).

What would be the best practice in this case?

Comment: I recomment looking into this project: https://medium.com/dailyjs/real-time-apps-with-typescript-integrating-web-sockets-node-angular-e2b57cbd1ec1

Comment: Thank you  but that project only describes how to build an app with socket.io, but I already know that. My question is if it is good practice to use both REST API and Websockets for one app if the realtime chat is not the main function of the app

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I can't help you with that

Comment: I am using a PHP REST API for retrieving data that stays mostly static, and using socket io(Node.js) to emit data that updates frequently real time and it works well. Why does it feel wrong to you?